# Custom TableView Error

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, custom-cell

I am trying to create a custom table view but stumble upon every code. As of right now, I have this below. It's messy and probably wrong but could someone help?

Also, I keep getting an error code

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

```
import UIKit

class tableOutlineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var names = ["Max", "Bill", "Reagan", "Mikayla", "Jessie", "Sierra", "Jeff", "Erik", "Landon"]
    var numbers = ["35", "33", "29", "27", "25", "23", "19", "15", "11"]
    var photo = [UIImage(named: "Person1"), UIImage(named: "Person2"), UIImage(named: "Groceries"), UIImage(named: "Person3"), UIImage(named: "Person4"), UIImage(named: "Person5"), UIImage(named: "Person6"), UIImage(named: "Person7")]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

        cell.images.image = photo[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.number.text = numbers[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your CustomCell class here

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the following line because it's unable to force unwrap `CustomCell`:

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
```

As you may be using `Nib` for your custom cell, you should firstly get it registered in `viewDidLoad`.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_NIB_NAME, bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to define identifier(CustomCell) inside attribute inspector of your Xib file of custom cell. So you when you are doing force unwrapped you are getting nil. Also avoid doing force unwrapped to avoid the crash. Have refactored the code :-

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
  cell.images.image = photo[indexPath.row]
  cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
  cell.number.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
  return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all please do not populate your tableview with multiple arrays. These arrays can easily go out of sync and can cause a crash. You should ideally create a `struct` class having name, age and photo as its elements. Then you should have an array of struct class to populate your table view.

Here as well in you name array you have 9 elements whereas your image array has 8 elements. This is causing your app to crash as cell for row at indexpath method is not able to find the 9th image.

```
cell.images.image = photo[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I took everyone's advice and when I run the code below, I get zero errors. But in the simulator, it shows an empty tableView and the image I placed above the tableView is another image from another View Controller. I don't know if it's the code or something else.

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? CustomCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
    cell.images.image = photo[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.numbers.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```

and my CustomCell

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numbers: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}